# What to return for strongly typed result including errors in a HttpGet? ActionResult<T> where T is FileContentResult doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm trying to return an image and in some cases error codes. At first I tried to return `Task<FileContentResult>`, which works when I have something to return. But if I want to e.g. `return BadRequest()`, I get a compiler error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult'

To fix this I return an `ActionResult` instead. And it works. But it kind of accepts anything. I want to be clear about what I want to return. Is there any way to use the strongly typed `ActionResult<T>` or something similar so that returning any of `File` (for the 200 success) and `BadRequest`, `NotFound` etc will work?

```
    [HttpGet("path")]
    [Produces("image/jpeg", "image/webp", "text/plain")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<FileContentResult>> Get(/*parameters*/)
    {
        if(/*invalid parameters*/)
        {
           return BadRequest("invalid parameters");
        }
        Byte[] image = GetImage();
        return File(image, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

Comment: You know, exceptions are a thing.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne I'm trying to return proper error codes and keep with the asp net conventions.

Comment: Try to return an IActionResult

Comment: The exceptions can be caught by middleware to return proper JSON responses.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `IActionResult`

```
        [HttpGet("path")]
        [Produces("image/jpeg", "image/webp", "text/plain")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(/*parameters*/)
        {
            if(/*invalid parameters*/)
            {
               return BadRequest("invalid parameters");
            }
            Byte[] image = GetImage();
            return File(image, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is how to return strongly typed `ActionResult<T>` where T = FileContentResult (or how to behave like `FileContentResult` with `ActionResult<T>`). I know `IActionResult` works but it doesn't indicate return type.

Comment: Ok, if you want to be clear about what you want to return, add         [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The generic type param for `ActionResult<T>` is for a serializable type. Essentially, it's going to return an `ObjectResult`, and therefore, can handle other result types like `BadRequestObjectResult`, etc. as well. However, `FileContentResult` does not inherit from `ObjectResult` and is not a serializable type. Therefore, it's ineligible to be used here.

If you're returning a file and you need to be able to return other status code results, then all you can use is `IActionResult`, which will obviously allow any possible result type.

The `ProducesResponseType` attribute can be used for documentation purposes, but it won't impact the actual return type in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I would throw an HTTPRequestException and set the http response code that makes the most sense to you.

If I were another developer looking at your code, it would make sense to me seeing the FileContentResult as the concrete type and then also see the thrown HTTPRequestException for the invalid parameters.

```
[HttpGet("path")]
[Produces("image/jpeg", "image/webp", "text/plain")]
public async Task<ActionResult<FileContentResult>> Get(/*parameters*/)
{
    if(/*invalid parameters*/)
    {
       throw new HttpResponseException(/* invalid parameters message */, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    }
    Byte[] image = GetImage();
    return File(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Convention is important to me too and I think doing it this way is a convention I've seen in several codebases.